# "I remember a time" vs. "I remember the time"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

> - I remember a time she was working as a waitress.
> - I remember the time she was working as a waitress.

Which of these is correct? And why?

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct. The second implies there was only one period when she worked as a waitress. The first refers to one *of possibly several* periods of employment as a waitress.

Comment: In other words it is entirely regular to the rules governing use of the definite/indefinite article.

Comment: But is that true in this case?  To me it seems that the word "time" muddies the water so to speak and makes the distinction less clear.  I think this needs more exploring.